# Positioning components within a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to precisely position a component in a LinearLayout. The LinearLayout is horizontal (ImageButton-TextView-ImageButton). The image below shows the problem. The numbers (the TextView) are not centered vertically or horizontally with respect to the ImageButtons.(Red lines indicating centers). As you can see in the code, I have the TextView component layout set to center|center. The numbers are always between 0 and 99.

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="25dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game4PreviousButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/previousbutton"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:onClick="clickCheck"
        android:src="@drawable/previousbutton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/game4Step"
        android:layout_width="80dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/game4step1"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/game4NextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:contentDescription="@string/nextbutton"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:onClick="clickNext"
        android:src="@drawable/nextbutton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: have try to set layout weightSum to 99

and weight of 33 to each component, i posted below an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/game4PreviousButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/previousbutton"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="clickCheck"
                android:src="@drawable/previousbutton" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/game4Step"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/game4step1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="01"
            android:textSize="50sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/game4NextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:contentDescription="@string/nextbutton"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="clickNext"
                android:src="@drawable/nextbutton" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is ever so close. The number is centered horizontally and vertically. The only problem is that a double-digit number takes more horizontal space than a single-digit number, such that when it transitions from 9 to 10, the buttons move farther apart. I had compensated for this before with `android:layout_width="80dip"` in the TextView, replacing this line in your code addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

I Assume that the `LinearLayout` is not the xml parent element since there is no `<?xml  />` directly above it, or maybe you forgot it. But

I believe you are looking for the following :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game4Step"
    android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/game4step1"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Also change LinearLayout to

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

and

`android:layout_weight="1"` can be removed.

and make both IMageButtons

`android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. With this, the horizontal position remains the same and the vertical position goes up, but too much.

Comment: i made a mistake. Try the code above now, also set the LinearLayout height to wrap_content instead of giving it 0dp and weight 1

Comment: did you make your buttons have the same height attributes as the textview?